# SharePoint designer 2010 unable to update task list due date

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-tasks-list

[image]I created a task approval Serial Workflow Designer 2010. So once first user complete the task next user will get the task due date adding six minutes.
I'm doing this Inside the task workflow BEFORE A TASK IS ASSIGNED I've written below step

Add 6 minitues to Variable CreateDate (Output to Variable Date01)

Set Task Field Due Date to Variable Date01

Here the problem is as per above code for all approvals Due Date in Task list is setting same date and time. When I check in Log, I have noticed in Log Due Date is updating correctly but in Task its update the same due date for every user. Then I tried below option to update the due date but in this option due date is not updating. could you please advice how to set due date in task list for all users in serial workflow after 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Update list Item" action, try to use "Set Task Field" action to change the Due Date field for task list.

[image]

**Update:**

Since the Due Date field is for the current task that all users participated, the due date for all the users will update with the new due date when the workflow triggered.It's by design.

As a workaround, you can use SharePoint 2013 workflow platform "Assign a task" action to assign task for users one by one, and update due date individually.

Comment: Hellofiona,as per your above post after Set Task Field Due Date I'm getting the updated due date in log but in Task List Due Date column its not updating the set field value due date. Its taking the same old due date for all approvers one by one. Here I'm using Desinger 2010 Serial Workflow.

Comment: I noticied, In BEFORE A TASK IS ASSINGED in Log after setting due date I'm getting the correct updated due date. But In WHEN A TASK IS PENDING I checked the same Log but there is showing old due date not the updated one which we set above. And the Due Date value which I'm getting under WHEN A TASK IS PENDING this value only gets updated in Task List Due Date column.